# Remove the authentication of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel project which requires authentication.

Now, I want to remove this system for temporary debugging purpose.

I am checking the `src/auth.php`, however can't find the on/off config.

It might be too basic, but I need some help to start.

Thank you very much.

(I am newbee for laravel (but familliar with symfony) , so it might too basic question but this is the place I need to start.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the auth middleware from which you want to access in your routes/web.php

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
});
```